# Show that Series $\sum \frac{2^{n}(z+3)^{n}}{3n}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> $\sum \frac{2^{n}(z+3)^{n}}{3n}$ show that the Series diverges for $|z+3|=\frac{1}{2}$

I have to estimate radius of convergence for this series. With Ratio-Test I already figured out that if $|z+3|<\frac{1}{2}$ the series converges and if $|z+3|>\frac{1}{2}$ it diverges. But for $|z+3|=\frac{1}{2}$ I'm lost. I could show with direct comparioson Test that it diverges absolutly but absolut divergence doesn't implies divergence. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is wrong.  The series converges when $z+3=-\frac  1 2$.

Comment: Why ask about the series with the $3$ in the denominator? Try to [reduce the questions to its bare bones](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#31696), otherwise it looks like you didn't really work on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more straightforward manner to find the radius of convergence is using [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test) for complex series. You'll only need to make the appropriate change of variables for $z$, and then the result follows.

Comment: thank you this is a great hint

Comment: I think I can solve the problem now